# Error al enviar datos por POST a un formulario de Mautic

Tags: angular, ionic, post

Estoy teniendo problemas al intentar enviar datos mediante POST a un formulario dado de alta en Mautic.

Mi idea es que desde una app en ionic pueda enviar los datos recogidos de un formulario hacia mautic, pero siempre me está dando el mismo error cuando ejecuto el POST desde código (ya que desde postman funciona correctamente). Estoy haciendo debug de los errores, los muestro a continuación:

**Errores que me aparecen en la consola de Chrome**

POST https://mautic.midominio.com/form/submit?formId=1 400

**Errores que aparecen en el log de mautic**

```
mautic.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException: "Invalid json message received" at /var/www/vhosts/midominio.com/mautic/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/EventListener/BodyListener.php line 127 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\BadRequestHttpException(code: 0): Invalid json message received at /var/www/vhosts/midominio.com/mautic/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/EventListener/BodyListener.php:127)"} []
```

**Desde Postman el formato de los datos que está funcionando es este:**

```
{
    "mauticform": {"nombre":"Alberto", "formId": 1}
}
```

**Pruebas que he realizado:**

- He definido los headers para que no haya problema de CORS en el server
- He comprobado también que el formulario esté activo y que el
  name del campo sea "Nombre"
- He intentado pasarle el objeto sin encomillar las keys
- He intentado pasarle los valores sin la key "mauticform"

**esta es la función que envía la solicitud post**

```
sendToMautic(){
    const url = 'https://mautic.mydomain.com/form/submit?formId=1';

    let datos = {
      "mauticform": {"nombre":"Alberto", "formId": "1"}
    }

    this.http.post(url, datos, {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
    .then(data => {

      console.log('ok', data);

    })
    .catch(error => {

      console.log('Error', error);

    });

  }
```

Comment: Claro que está funcionando bien desde PostMan porque lo mandas como JSON, el error dice claramente: ""Invalid json message received"", no sé cómo lo haces (no lo detallas en tu pregunta).

Comment: Gracias por contestar @fredyfx, he editado la pregunta con la función que envía la solicitud POST, ya te digo que he probado a enviar el objeto de mil formas y siempre obtengo el mismo error

Comment: de nada, espero te sea de utilidad la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución, explico:

**He probado con lo que has propuesto**

```
let datos = JSON.stringify({ mauticform: {"nombre":"Alberto", "formId": "1"}});
```

Pero el módulo HTTP de ionic me decía que sólo acepta objetos, por lo que he vuelto a ponerle el objeto tal cual lo he planteado en la pregunta:

```
let datos = {
  "mauticform": {"nombre":"Alberto", "formId": "1"}
}
```

Y aquí la clave: **Establecer un serializado para los datos que se envían justo antes de hacer la solicitud:**

```
this.http.setDataSerializer('json');
```

Y luego la llamada POST:

```
this.http.post(url, datos, {})
```

Ha funcionado correctamente :)

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
let datos = {
  "mauticform": {"nombre":"Alberto", "formId": "1"}
}
```

Remplaza por:

```
let datos = JSON.stringify({ mauticform: {"nombre":"Alberto", "formId": "1"}});
```

Nótese que mauticform carece de comillas iniciales y finales.

Comment: He publicado la solución, era cuestión de serializar los datos con un método del módulo http de ionic. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @fredyfx

Comment: ¡Perfecto! sigue desarrollando con todo el power 2.0!!! :D Buenas vibras lml